# Pop Up in Google Sheets for Viewers and Editors

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Is there a way to create a pop-up messsage that shows in Google Sheets not only to Editors/Collaborators but also to those with "view only" privileges?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to run a script when a view-only user opens or otherwise interacts with a spreadsheet. Scripts only run when the user has edit access. See [triggers and events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).